# Clone entire document node and set it as new document in another window

Tags: javascript, html

I'm wondering whether there's a straightforward way to clone a `document` node from one window and import it into another, eg iframe or popup. Right now here's what I do:

```js
const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
const importedDocElement = iframe.contentDocument.importNode(document.documentElement, true);
iframe.contentDocument.documentElement.replaceWith(importedDocElement);
```

Now this mostly works, but then there are some other missing parts like doctype and other metadata bound to the document node. Of course one can transfer missing parts one by one, but maybe there's a way to copytransfer the document node itself.

Comment: Wouldn't creating such a clone lead to an infinite creation of documents?

Comment: Only if the copying script is always running, which is in my case special event driven. Your question can be also applied to any cloned element which contains the cloning script. So of course it should be kept in mind.